# Multi-channel or multi-colum matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

In OpenCV I'm working with some data that looks like this:

```
//label     A    B    C
//   0      1    2    0
//   1      2    1    1
//   2      3    0    4
//   3      4    2    3
//   4      1    1    1
```

This data (columns A, B and C) can be stored in either a single-channel 5x3 matrix or in a 5x1 matrix with three channels. More concretely, for this example both definitions of *data* will do the job:

```
cv::Mat data(5, 3, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat data(5, 1, CV_8UC3);
```

My question is: Is there a reason for choosing one of the declarations from above and not the other?

P.S.:This is a general doubt and not a question to a particular problem.

Comment: If you can have more than 4 columns, you'd better to follow the first approach.

Comment: Is there some performance difference between both approaches?

Comment: No, data are laid out in memory the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do with this data.
Some OpenCV operations are easier to do on a single pixel plane but others might be multichannel oriented.

I would guess that single plane (`C1`) would be more suitable for most situations though you can easily switch representations using `cv::reshape()`. In fact, choose any one and use `reshape()` to generate another view of the same memory.